# Embedding image in laravel markdown email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to embed an image into my markdown email but it's not loading correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltmAY.png

This is my mail template:

```js
@component('mail::message')
# {{ $mailData['title'] }}

![{{ $mailData['appName'] }}]({{ asset($mailData['image'])}})

{!! $mailData['body'] !!}

Saludos,

{{ $mailData['appName'] }}
@endcomponent
```

This is the value of $mailData['image']:

'/img/misc/default.jpg'

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You still have to put it in an `<img>` tag

Comment: And of course send the email as HTML

Comment: Considering the details of the image, I think it's already sent as HTML. That's default for Laravel's mailers.

Comment: Check the source of the email and verify the URL to the image actually works.

Comment: What's the output of `asset($mailData['image'])`?

Comment: This is what I see after inspecting the mail: https://i.imgur.com/aSu8HND.png

Comment: I see you're sending from a localhost. That may be throwing things off, especially if you're not accessing the email from the same computer as the web server.

Comment: Yeah I'm from localhost

Answer (score 4):

You can try this markdown:

```
![Image_Alter_Text](PAHT_OF_IMAGE)
```

- You have to pass complete path of image, and you get complete path by using `Storage::url($file_name)`. Store image path in variable and pass in markdown.

**For example** :

```
![DemoImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bENi3.jpg)
```

---

*Note: The image (logo of stackoverflow) is used in this comments is only for demo purpose.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `html` to add an image to your `markdown`:

```
@component('mail::message')
# {{ $mailData['title'] }}

<img src="{{asset('img/logo.png')}}" style="width:30%" alt="App Logo">

...

@endcomponent
```

Also you can use the `style` tag to customize the `image`.

Be aware if you are in `localhost`, you aren't going to see the image in the email (unless you are using [mailhogh](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) to test your emails).

As far as I know, the image has to be in your server hosted, so the image will not attached on the email.

Your server need an IP public or a domain to be able to see the images within the email.

Comment: More about rendering a QR code in Laravel Blade: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330324/1883256

Answer (score 1):

Just add the image as an attachment, and you can reference it in the markdown with `cid:imagename.png`

```php
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    // ...
    
    public function attachments()
    {
        return [
            Attachment::fromData(function () {return $this->image_data;}, 'image.png')
            ->withMime('image/png'),
        ];
    }
}
```

```markdown
# My markdown template
![Image](cid:image.png)
```